# SharePoint 2010 Foundation

Tags: document, library, version-history

A new sharepoint foundation site has been established for just under a year.  It contains many document libraries for several departments.  Only the last three versions of a document are tracked.

What is the process when a document has more than 3 versions shown.
Would the oldest version be deleted?

Thanks,

Di Mosca

Answer (score 3):

The versioning in SharePoint is tracking Major (published with everyone, everything having 1.0, 2.0, etc.) and/or Minor (X.1, X.2, etc.). According to how you have setup Versioning via the List/Library Settings you would have Major or Major and Minor.

In both cases when you limit versions, basically the OLDEST are deleted, so you would 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 as soon as you check-in to increment to 0.4 than 0.1 will cease to exist.

For Major versions, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 - creating 4.0 will remove 1.0 plus Minor versions, if also enabled.

Comment: Can you configure this limit (of keeping 3 versions) to be higher (or even infinite)?

Comment: yes, actually via the list settings by typing a number in either Minor/Major text boxes. Not Infinite for sure, and not best practice either to leave this uncontrolled